# How to update the values of Observable Array through Select element

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a observable Array and I display that in a select element, for example if I have 4 elements in the array, then I will have 4 Select Element.

When I change the items in the Select list the observable array seems to be unchanged.

Please help me on how to update the observable array.

The jsfiddle for the same is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/saamisolutions/M8m8R/2/)

HTML Code

```
    <div>
    <div>
        <table>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: players">
                <tr>
                    <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: age"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: country"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: trophies"></td>
                    <td>
                        <button data-bind="click: $root.editPlayers">Edit</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div data-bind="with: editPlayer">
         <h3>Edit</h3>
Name:
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: name" />
        <br/>Age:
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: age" />
        <br/>Country:
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: country" />
        <span data-bind="foreach: trophies">
            <br/>Tropies:
            <select data-bind="options: $root.trophiesList, value:$data, optionsCaption:'Choose..'"></select>    
        </span>

    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript Code

```
    var player = function (name, age, country, trophyArray) {
    this.name = ko.observable(name);
    this.age = ko.observable(age);
    this.country = ko.observable(country);
    this.trophies = ko.observableArray(trophyArray);
};

var playerModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.players = [
        new player('Roger', 32, 'swiss', ['AO','FO','WB','US']),
        new player('Murray', 28, 'Scott', ['WB','US'])];

    self.editPlayer = ko.observable();
    self.trophiesList = ['AO','US','FO', 'WB'];

    self.editPlayers = function (player) {
        self.editPlayer(player);
    }

}

ko.applyBindings(new playerModel());
```

Comment: JSFiddler was pointing to a old version, I have updated the link again

Comment: your model is wrong. you dont do a for each option, just set options parameter with an observable array, then the value parameter should be something like selectedTrophy. check docs again

Comment: @bto.rdz I have a list of trophy and I am displaying each trophy in a separate select element, allowing each to be changed. May be I will also try multi select option.

Comment: multiselect would be better in your case, the current problem is that you have an observable array but their items are not obserbable. One solution wold be to crate a new trophy class and a pbservable name property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I have created an updated fiddle for you

```
self.players = [
    new player('Roger', 32, 'swiss', [{key: ko.observable('AO')},{key:ko.observable('FO')},{key:ko.observable('WB')},{key: ko.observable('US')}]),
    new player('Roger', 32, 'swiss', [{key: ko.observable('AO')},{key:ko.observable('FO')},{key:ko.observable('WB')},{key: ko.observable('US')}])];
```

http://jsfiddle.net/M8m8R/4/

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Remove the following markup:

`<span data-bind="foreach: trophies">`
 and the closing `</span>` tag.

Then use the `selectedOptions` binding to manage the trophies array:

```
    <br/>Tropies:
    <select data-bind="options: $root.trophiesList, selectedOptions:trophies, optionsCaption:'Choose..'" multiple="true" size="10"></select>
```

The user can then select/deselect multiple trophies.

Comment: Thanks. Multi select serves the purpose but I wanted single dropdown for each array element and noticed each item of the observable array should be observable as in the above example.